# How to remove the error message with array index

Tags: java, for-loop

Why am I getting an error for the last index?

```
public class Myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myarray =  {1,2,3,4} ; 

     for (int index=0 ;  index <4 ; index++);    
     {       
         System.out.println(myarray [index]); 
     }
       
    }
  }
```

The "index" after println is highlighted in Eclipse and a message says: "index cannot be resolved to a variable".

How is it possible to remove the error message with this array index?

Comment: `for (int index=0 ;  index <4 ; index++);` - remove the last `;`

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```
for (int index=0 ;  index <myarray.length ; index++) 
 {
     System.out.println(myarray [index]); 
 }
```

Comment: There are no benefits of these answer, as this is not going to help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your `;` is closing the for-loop.
Should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myarray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        System.out.println(myarray[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a `;` after the `for` loop, just remove it.
Instead of:

```
for (int index=0 ;  index <4 ; index++);
```

Do:

```
for (int index=0 ;  index <4 ; index++)
```

The `;` means "the for loop ends here". As `index` was declared inside the `for`, it's not visible in the next block.